# How to make auto resizing UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout

I am working on auto layout. I have an UILabel I want it to Cover whole Screen.

[This is I want and Working fine on iPhone4 and iPhone5][1]

It is working fine on iPhone5 and iPhone4 but in iPhone 6 my UILable Shrinks.

[Problem in iPhone6][1]

How can Resolve this issue.

I have turned size classes off.

Link of Constraint :    https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiFP1.png

Comment: Nothing meaningful on screenshot by link. Show good screenshot with all constraints to UILabel.

Comment: i want this label to fit on whole screen

Comment: Add constraints between all the sides of UILabel and superview. I can't help you without all the details of your problem.

Comment: you have to use constraints, top constraints also work and ya don't fix height and width.

Comment: @kirander I have simple one UILabel as shown in omg i just want it to cover whole screen

Comment: Maybe you added constraints with margins?

Comment: add screenshot of both working and not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i got you. set Leading, Trailing, Top Constraint to 0, 0 & 20(set as per your need) respectively. Secondly, select label & under Attributes Inspector set no. of Lines to 0 and you are done. Label height will be increased according to your text.

Comment: You also need to set the uilable to word wrap else the uilabel will not resize its height according to its content.

Comment: i have already took constraints so it is not compulsory to set uilabel to word wrap. You must try it first & then comment. thnk u anyways.